# Valgrind detects memory leak when dynamically allocated array of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently working on a C++ application that uses a dynamic array of pointers. I am running valgrind on it and it does detect a memory leak in my constructor.

This is what my class looks like:

```
class CustomerOrder
{
private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_product;
    unsigned int m_cntItem;
    Item** m_lstItem;
    static size_t m_widthField;
public:
    CustomerOrder();
    CustomerOrder(const std::string& customerOrder);
    CustomerOrder(const CustomerOrder& customerOrder);
    CustomerOrder& operator=(const CustomerOrder& customerOrder) = delete;
    CustomerOrder(CustomerOrder&& customerOrder) noexcept;
    CustomerOrder& operator=(CustomerOrder&& customerOrder) noexcept;
    ~CustomerOrder();
};
```

This is my constructor implementation:

```
CustomerOrder::CustomerOrder(const std::string& customerOrder)
{
    Utilities utilities;
    size_t next_pos = 0;
    size_t start_pos = 0;
    bool more = true;
    

    m_name = utilities.extractToken(customerOrder, next_pos, more);
    m_product = utilities.extractToken(customerOrder, next_pos, more);
    m_cntItem = 0;

    start_pos = next_pos;

    while (more) {
        utilities.extractToken(customerOrder, next_pos, more);
        m_cntItem++;
    }

    m_lstItem = new Item*[m_cntItem];

    more = true;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_cntItem; i++) {
        m_lstItem[i] = new Item(utilities.extractToken(customerOrder, start_pos, more));
    }

    if (utilities.getFieldWidth() > m_widthField) {
        m_widthField = utilities.getFieldWidth();
    }
}
```

These are my move constructor and move assignment operator.

```
CustomerOrder::CustomerOrder(CustomerOrder&& customerOrder) noexcept : m_lstItem(nullptr)
{
    *this = std::move(customerOrder);
}

CustomerOrder& CustomerOrder::operator=(CustomerOrder&& customerOrder) noexcept
{
    if (this != &customerOrder) {
        if (m_lstItem) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_cntItem; i++) {
                delete this->m_lstItem[i];
            }
        }

        delete [] m_lstItem;

        this->m_name = customerOrder.m_name;
        this->m_product = customerOrder.m_product;
        this->m_cntItem = customerOrder.m_cntItem;
        this->m_lstItem = customerOrder.m_lstItem;

        customerOrder.m_lstItem = nullptr;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Finally, this is my destructor.

```
CustomerOrder::~CustomerOrder()
{
    if (m_lstItem) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_cntItem; i++) {
            delete this->m_lstItem[i];
        }
    }

    delete [] m_lstItem;
    m_lstItem = nullptr;
}
```

Based on the above information, can anyone help me understand why the above errors occur?
This is the output from Valgrind:

```
==9320== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9320==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==9320==   total heap usage: 70 allocs, 69 frees, 103,891 bytes allocated
==9320== 
==9320== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9320==    at 0x4C3289F: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==9320==    by 0x10D67E: CustomerOrder::CustomerOrder(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (CustomerOrder.cpp:45)
==9320==    by 0x10F15C: main (ms2.cpp:102)
==9320== 
==9320== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9320==    definitely lost: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==9320==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9320==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9320==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9320==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I understand it happens in the constructor but I am not so sure how I can change the destructor accordingly.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: `*this = std::move(customerOrder);` It's a bad idea to do this in a constructor. `operator=` assumes that members of `*this` are properly initialized, but you are in fact calling it on an uninitialized object. On the very second line, `if (m_lstItem) {`, your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for your feedback. That has helped a lot. My previous warnings have disappeared however I am getting a new memory leak now in my constructor. Could you take a look if possible?

Comment: I ultimately solved my memory leak. I had forgotten to free the pointer in my move assignment operator. So, all I had to do was adding delete [] m_lstItem right after the for loop in that operator.